# How to play sound in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, audio

I want to achieve two things:

1. To play mp3/4 files with my programs**
2. To play soundwaves generated by my program's functions.

I do know how audio works and how to generate sample arrays to represent the audio. What I want to know is **how to interface my program with my computer's speakers**

I'm on **Windows** and
I'd like not to use any third party API else than windows' dependencies, and if it's impossible or too hard to do so, please tell me why

I suppose I need to use Windows.h and the winmm library, but I'm unsure, so my question is:
**what header(s) and functions within them do I need to use?**

Comment: C++ has no concept of multimedia, so you need to use a platform-specific audio API (ie, `PlaySound()`, DirectSound, XAudio2, etc), or a 3rd party audio library.

Comment: DirectSound is good, I remember a lot of games using fmod, I don't know if that's still a thing but maybe look into that too https://www.fmod.com

Comment: [You're not alone in wanting to find an answer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+to+play+sound+in+C%2B%2B), but as has been stated above, the problem is that you need to be able to interface with the audio hardware, which will require an API / Library to do so. The second problem is that playing a file and playing some raw, synthesised PCM buffers are two _very_ different problems. Audio programming is actually quite a challenge, but it will teach you a lot. Ultimately, it comes down to _what do you want to learn or achieve?_  In any case, this is not a question best fit for SO.

Comment: What do you mean with SO, fdcpp?

Comment: Thanks to you all for the comments

Comment: Stack Overflow (SO)